# Is BitmapTextureAtlas useful in Andengine GLES2

Tags: android, andengine

I read some threads about `BitmapTextureAtlas` in Andengine, but AFAIK, the newest version of `Andengine` dont need POT anymore. If I use many `ITexture`s instead of singe big `BitmapTextureAtlas` is better or not? (example, I have 1 background texture: 480x800 and some small sprite textures. All textures can be put in a 1024x1024 `BitmapTextureAtlas` --> I wasted memory, dont I?) Can anyone tell me about how useful `BitmapTextureAtlas` it is in GLES2? When I should use it? thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easier to use a BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas in GLES2
[jaym](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/bitmaptextureatlas-vs-buildablebitmaptextureatlas-t7269.html) describes it the diference [here](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/bitmaptextureatlas-vs-buildablebitmaptextureatlas-t7269.html).

"Buildable texture atlas allows andengine to automatically place the textures on the texture atlas whereas bitmap texture atlas requires you to manually define location on textures inside the texture atlas."

You can use one big BuildableTextureAtlas and automatically build multiple textures onto it, providing they fit. I take the lazy approach and make a BuildableTextureAtlas for each TextureRegion.

Onto the better news: The power of 2 rule now only applies to repeating backgrounds,
[Read RealMayo's explenation](http://www.andengine.org/forums/project-development-blogs/tech-support-tips-for-your-game-t12881.html#p54968). Keep in mind when creating your TextureAtlas to make it a little bigger then your image or it will fail to load.

Comment: tq!However, I must declare 1024x1024 Atlas instead 680x900 size (actually size I need for all my sprite) --> It wasted, didn't it?

Comment: I updated the Answer.
The power of 2 rule only applies to repeating backgrounds. So you could make a Texture Atlas 690x910